# Running 2 commands on Xaml Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am currently developing an application using WPF/ Xaml in MVVM format.

I am attempting to run 2 commands from one single button to close a control and delete the object the control was based on.

The viewmodels that these commands are created in are separate so i am unsure of how to do this in the Viewmodels.

I am hoping for a solution that just runs these 2 commands in the Xaml if this is possible

The code if necessary

```
<Button Grid.Column="4"
Command="{Binding DeleteCustom}"
Visibility="{Binding IsCustom}"/>
```

The other command i want to run is called

```
CancelCommand
```

I hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

There is only a single `Command` property that can be set to a single `ICommand` but you can create another command property in your view model that executes both commands and bind to this one:

```
public ICommand CompositeCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand<object>((arg) =>
{
    DeleteCustom.Execute(null);
    CancelCommand.Execute(null);
});
```

Comment: I did look into composite commands but the commands are in different viewmodels so im unsure of how i would run them both.
thats why i was trying to do it in the XAML, thanks though! :)

Comment: You can still only bind the Command property of the Button to a single command. I don't know what the point of defining the commands in different view models is when you still need to call them both. This seems like a design flaw.

Comment: Ok. i will attempt to do something with a composite command. thankyou for the advice.
I don't believe its a design flaw. Its a very large application. I can try moving the commands around but they aren't entirely related and putting them in the same viewmodel may not be desirable

Comment: Alternatively you could handle the Click event and invoke the command(s) programmatically. I guess the view must have access to both view models, otherwise you wouldn't be able to bind to both commands in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you write your command in a base class and override it

```
ViewModelBase
{

    public virtual ICommand CompositeCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand<object>((arg) =>
    {
        DeleteCustom.Execute(null);
        CancelCommand.Execute(null);
    });

    protected virtual DeleteCustom(object arg)
    {
       /.....
    }

    protected virtual CancelCommand(object arg)
    {
        /....
    }

    //..........
}


FirstViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // ...............

    protected override void  DeleteCustom(object arg)
    {
    }
    // ..........
}

SecondviewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     // ...............

    protected override void  CancelCommand(object arg)
    { 

    }
    // ..........
}
```